# Rails: How do I make a calculation using form input variables in the create action of a controller before saving it in the db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my form, the user inputs his/her weight and body fat percentage. In my controller create action, I want to calculate the lean mass of the person and save it to the lean_mass column in my db.

`lean_mass = weight * (1 - body_fat)`

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "stats", force: true do |t|
   t.integer  "user_id"
   t.integer  "weight"
   t.decimal  "body_fat"
   t.integer  "lean_mass"
   t.date     "date"
   t.datetime "created_at"
   t.datetime "updated_at"
 end
```

**stats/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @stat do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :date %>
  <%= f.date_field   :date %>

  <%= f.label :weight %>
  <%= f.number_field :weight %>

  <%= f.label :body_fat %>
  <%= f.number_field :body_fat, step: 0.1 %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**stats_controller.rb**

```
class StatsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user! #I'm using devise

def index
 @stats = current_user.stats
end

def new
 @stat = current_user.stats.build
end

def create
  ##
  ###How do I calculate and add lean_mass to stat_params here?###
  ##
  @stat = current_user.stats.build(stat_params)
  if @stat.save
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Stat was successfully created."
  else
    redirect_to dashboard_url, notice: "Problem creating stat."
  end
end

 private

 def stat_params
   params.require(:stat).permit(:date, :weight, :body_fat)
 end
end
```

I need help with the create action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Manually calculate & insert the lean mass:**

You will have to calculate the lean mass first:

```
lean_mass = params[:stat][:weight].to_i * (1 - params[:stat][:body_fat].to_i)
```

And then you can add it to the new `@stat` object

```
@stat = current_user.stats.build(stat_params.merge(:lean_mass => lean_mass))

# OR

@stat.lean_mass = lean_mass
```

Then you can go ahead and save the object.

### **Automatically handle the lean mass**

Assuming you validate the presence of the `weight` & `body_fat` columns like so:

*stat.rb*

```
validates_presense_of :weight, :body_fat
```

Since the `lean mass` is always dependant on the `weight` & `body_fat` I'd suggest two things:

1) You can **add a method** `lean_mass` in your model that returns the calculated value, so the column would no longer be necessary.

*stat.rb*

```
def lean_mass
  self.weight * (1 - self.body_fat)
end
```

2) Add an `after_save` [**callback**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) that calculates & stores the `lean_mass` value automatically

*stat.rb*

```
after_save { self.update(:lean_mass => self.weight * (1 - self.body_fat)) }
```

---

One of these solutions is highly suggested since you don't have to worry about the `lean mass` column in the `create` or `update` action.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and got this error:   String can't be coerced into Fixnum

Comment: You have to convert the weight & fat into integers before making calculations, I updated my answer. Check out the two other solutions

Comment: Perfect. Even better than the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks, TheChamp! You rock!